# Colorir Datagridview com comparação C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cores

Gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de colorir linha do datagridview sem utilizar um laço de repetição.

Eu tenho um estoque minimo e quando o disponível estiver abaixo do minimo gostaria de pintar a linha de vermelho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz dessa forma, mas ficou muito lento.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvEstoque_pecas.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    int disponivel = 0, minimo = 0;
    if (dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[i].Cells["disponivel"].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        disponivel = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[i].Cells[disponivel].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        disponivel = 0;
    }
    if (dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[i].Cells["minimo"].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        minimo = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[i].Cells["minimo"].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        minimo = 0;
    }

    if (disponivel < minimo)
        dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

}
```

Comment: Pesquise por RowDataBound, é um projeto Web ou Desktop?

Comment: É um projeto Windows Forms, Desktop.

Comment: Então não tem o RowDataBound, você pode tentar pelo CellFormatting

Comment: tente algo parecido com isso,  `DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Wheat;`  isso também pode ajudar ************https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento `CellFormatting` que será executado antes do render do seu `DataGridView` na tela durante o `DataBind()`.

```
private void dgvEstoque_pecas_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    DataGridViewRow row = dgvEstoque_pecas.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var cellDisponivel = e.Value;

    int disponivel = 0, minimo = 0;

    if (row.Cells["disponivel"].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        disponivel = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[disponivel].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        disponivel = 0;
    }

    if (row.Cells["minimo"].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        minimo = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["minimo"].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        minimo = 0;
    }

    if (disponivel < minimo)
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

}
```

Para adicionar o evento à sua grid você pode fazer diretamente pelo painel de propriedades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou se você só copiou e colou o código acima, pode vincular diretamente no `InitiliazeComponent()` em  seu `*.Designer.cs`.

```
this.dgvEstoque_pecas.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dgvEstoque_pecas_CellFormatting);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Leandro, funcionou perfeitamente e ficou bem mais rápido.